# how to get the last value of array after the if statement have been satisfied

Tags: c++

This is what I have so far. My problem is that the iteration function returns the first value of the array. I want it to return the last value after the if statement is satisfied.

This is solving equation using the [False Position Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method)

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double iteration(double u, double l);
double f (double x);
inline bool closerlimit(double u, double l);

double e;
void main()
{   
    cout << "Enter the upper Limit: " <<endl;
    double ul;
    cin >> ul;

    cout << "Enter The lower Limit: " <<endl;
    double ll;
    cin >> ll;

    cout<<"enter level of error: "<<endl;
    cin>>e;

    double r;
    r=iteration(ul,ll);
    cout<<"root is : "<< r<<endl;
}

double f(double x)
{
    return exp(x)+5*x;
}

// Evaluating the closer limit to the root
// to make sure that the closer limit is the
// one that moves and the other one is fixed
inline bool closerlimit(double u, double l)
{
    return fabs(f(u)) > fabs(f(l));
}
```

This is my iteration function. It only returns the first value of the array. I want it so that after the if statement is satisfied, this function will return the latest value of the root array.

```
double iteration(double u, double l)
{
    double root[100], re=0;
    for (int i=0; i<=20; i++)
    {
        {   
            root[i] = u - ((f(u)*(l-u)) / (f(l)-f(u)));
            if (closerlimit(u,l))
                l = root[i];
            else
                u = root[i];

            double re=0;
            re=abs((root[i]-root[i-1])/root[i])*100;

            if (re<=e) {break;}
        }
        cout<<"r = "<<root[i]<<endl;
        cout<<"re = "<<re<<endl;

        return (root[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: root[i] = u - ((f(u)*(l-u)) / (f(l)-f(u))) really ?

Comment: that formula works..it calculates the latest root.. my problem is that how can i return the latest root

Comment: Oh, i'm pretty sure it works, but it's the code that i know nothing about and i see that line, which has no meaning whatsoever unless analyzed carefully, or indeed debuged for a random value. I reckon it needs a comment or a different name for a function than ' f() ', but that's just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can always save what you want to return in a local variable.

```
double iteration(double u, double l)
{
    double root[100], re=0;
    double ret = 0.0; //added
    int i; // you'll want to use i in cout
    for (i=0; i<=20; i++)
    {
        {root[i] = u - ((f(u)*(l-u)) / (f(l)-f(u)));
        if (closerlimit(u,l))
            l = root[i];
        else
            u = root[i];

        double re=0;
        re=abs((root[i]-root[i-1])/root[i])*100;

        if (re<=e) {
            ret=root[i]; // save the value;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout<<"r = "<<root[i]<<endl; // well, when break is not met, this is uninitialized value
    cout<<"re = "<<re<<endl;

    return ret; // defaulted to 0
}
```